# How i can lint only changed files in PR azure DevOps?

Tags: api, azure-devops, yaml, eslint, pull-request

Suppose I need to check with ESlint a file that is changed in the PR

How can I get a list of changeable files in a Pull Request in order to submit them to the linter?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/systempullrequesttargetbranch-in-pipeline-exposes/969429 i found this